# How to manipulate browser history and catch browser back/forward buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, pushstate

I've been searching for couple of hours now trying to make a simple browser history manipulation.

I have a couple of menu links and I bind click handlers to them. Links' href's are just hashes: `href="#Home"` or `href="#About"`.

I would like to display a subpage when user clicks on link, without page reload and change the browser url.

I've also tried this basic example with pushState() but it doesn't work:
http://jsbin.com/wecubizovu/1/edit?html,js,console

http://jsbin.com/wecubizovu

When I run this in Chrome, I expect that, if user clicks on the link, he'll have #asd appended to url and **popstate won't change**. Why is popstate being triggered? How can I make it so that when user clicks on a link, I append hash to browser url and when user clicks browser back button, I catch that event and display the piece of page that I want?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `a` element has a `href` of `''` which is still executed if you do not prevent the default action and this somehow messes up what you want to do.
Changing your function to

```
$("#asd").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert("jo");
  window.history.pushState("", document.title, "#asd");
});
```

achieves what you are looking for.

EDIT: Links: http://jsbin.com/sosozeteti

http://jsbin.com/sosozeteti/1/edit?html,js

Comment: Oooooooh that was the issue. I also just discovered that I added click handler to class and it was invoked twice everytime because of DOM propagation...
Thanks! Took me couple of hours for this small details...